# vector.push_back is not resulting in the right value being pushed back

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

I am practicing merge sort (for interview prep purposes). I am running into a very strange issue with vectors. It seems that pushing a certain value back onto the vector does not result in that value actually being put there. I could be missing something obvious, but I am not sure. Here is the code for the merge sort (some print statements were added in to understand what was going wrong)

```
void merge(std::vector<int> *vec, int low, int middle, int high) {
    printf("Entering Merge(%d, %d, %d)\n", low, middle, high);
    std::vector<int> helper;
    for(int i = low; i <= high; ++i) {
        helper.push_back( (*vec)[i] );
    }
    std::cout << "Array being worked on: [";
    for(auto &p : helper) {
        std::cout << p << ", ";
    } std::cout << "]" << std::endl;

    int helperLeft = low, helperRight = middle + 1, vecIndex = low;
    while(helperLeft <= middle && helperRight <= high) {
        if(helper[helperLeft] <= helper[helperRight]) {
            (*vec)[vecIndex] = helper[helperLeft];
            ++helperLeft;
            std::cout << "Helper Left: " << helperLeft << std::endl; 
        }
        else {
            (*vec)[vecIndex] = helper[helperRight];
            ++helperRight;
            std::cout << "Helper Right: " << helperRight << std::endl;
        }
        ++vecIndex;
        std::cout << "Current Index: " << vecIndex   << std::endl;
    }

    // Copy over the remaining elements into the array
    while(helperLeft <= middle) {
        std::cout << "Entered Left Remaining" << std::endl;
        (*vec)[vecIndex] = helper[helperLeft];
        ++helperLeft;
        ++vecIndex;
    }

    while(helperRight <= high) {
        std::cout << "Entered Right Remaining" << std::endl;
        (*vec)[vecIndex] = helper[helperRight];
        ++helperRight;
        ++vecIndex;
    }
    std::cout << "Resulting Array: [";
    for(int i = low; i < high; ++i) {
        std::cout << (*vec)[i] << ", ";
    } std::cout << (*vec)[high] << "]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void mergeSort(std::vector<int> *vec, int low, int high) {
    if(low < high) {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        mergeSort(vec, low, middle);
        mergeSort(vec, middle + 1, high);
        merge(vec, low, middle, high);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> array({2, 25, 1, 1, 5});
    mergeSort(&array, 0, array.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: As an aside, you could make your code a fair bit cleaner by passing vec by reference instead of by pointer.

Comment: You should try replacing `operator[]` with `at` to make sure your indexes are valid.

Comment: This should be fairly easy to debug... Can you at least show your testcase? This is two functions, fine, but you didn't show how you call them and what the output was...

Comment: in some algorithm books, the index of array is range [1..N], in C/C++ world, you should convert to [0...N-1]

Comment: The problem is that you cannot use the indices `low`, `middle` and `high` to access the `helper`. Helper's indices start at `0` and go to (including) `high-low`. You'll need to recompute `helperLow = 0, helperMiddle = middle - low + 1, helperHigh = high-low` (I might be off by one).

Comment: @dyp I realized the same thing about 30 seconds ago and came to report that back. It works perfectly now, thanks a lot!